# Getting WebSocketC++ to work

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, openssl, websocket++

WebSocket C++ is a, well, a C++ library for web sockets. The library is located [here](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp). The library is header only so I do not need to compile that, however I do need OpenSSL and Boost. The version Boost I am using is 1.61. I included boost into the project and that got rid of a bunch of errors. I then needed to install OpenSSL because it was giving me a

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/conf.h': No such file or directory`.

I attempted to compile OpenSSL but I was unable to. I keep getting a error so I found prebuilt binaries for OpenSSL. I downloaded them and setup it in Visual Studio (include path and lib) and then I started getting a bunch of errors.

https://prntscr.com/f33def and http://prntscr.com/f33dwa (Sorry for bad formatting)

The example code I am using is from their github page (examples->debug_client)

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>
 #include <chrono>
 typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;
 using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
 using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
 using websocketpp::lib::bind;

// pull out the type of messages sent by our config
 typedef websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;  
typedef websocketpp::lib::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ptr; 
 typedef client::connection_ptr connection_ptr;



class perftest {
public:
typedef perftest type;
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::micro> dur_type;

perftest() {
    m_endpoint.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
    m_endpoint.set_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all);

    // Initialize ASIO
    m_endpoint.init_asio();

    // Register our handlers
    m_endpoint.set_socket_init_handler(bind(&type::on_socket_init, this, ::_1));
    //m_endpoint.set_tls_init_handler(bind(&type::on_tls_init,this,::_1));
    m_endpoint.set_message_handler(bind(&type::on_message, this, ::_1, ::_2));
    m_endpoint.set_open_handler(bind(&type::on_open, this, ::_1));
    m_endpoint.set_close_handler(bind(&type::on_close, this, ::_1));
    m_endpoint.set_fail_handler(bind(&type::on_fail, this, ::_1));
}

void start(std::string uri) {
    websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
    client::connection_ptr con = m_endpoint.get_connection(uri, ec);

    if (ec) {
        m_endpoint.get_alog().write(websocketpp::log::alevel::app, ec.message());
        return;
    }

    //con->set_proxy("http://humupdates.uchicago.edu:8443");

    m_endpoint.connect(con);

    // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
    m_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    m_endpoint.run();
}

void on_socket_init(websocketpp::connection_hdl) {
    m_socket_init = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

context_ptr on_tls_init(websocketpp::connection_hdl) {
    m_tls_init = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    context_ptr ctx = websocketpp::lib::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);

    try {
        ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
            boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
            boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 |
            boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return ctx;
}

void on_fail(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    client::connection_ptr con = m_endpoint.get_con_from_hdl(hdl);

    std::cout << "Fail handler" << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->get_state() << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->get_local_close_code() << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->get_local_close_reason() << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->get_remote_close_code() << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->get_remote_close_reason() << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->get_ec() << " - " << con->get_ec().message() << std::endl;
}

void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    m_open = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    m_endpoint.send(hdl, "", websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);
}
void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr) {
    m_message = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    m_endpoint.close(hdl, websocketpp::close::status::going_away, "");
}
void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl) {
    m_close = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Socket Init: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<dur_type>(m_socket_init - m_start).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TLS Init: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<dur_type>(m_tls_init - m_start).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Open: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<dur_type>(m_open - m_start).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Message: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<dur_type>(m_message - m_start).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Close: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<dur_type>(m_close - m_start).count() << std::endl;
}
private:
client m_endpoint;

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_start;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_socket_init;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_tls_init;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_open;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_message;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_close;
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
std::string uri = "wss://echo.websocket.org";

if (argc == 2) {
    uri = argv[1];
}

try {
    perftest endpoint;
    endpoint.start(uri);
}
catch (const std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (websocketpp::lib::error_code e) {
    std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
}
catch (...) {
    std::cout << "other exception" << std::endl;
}
}
```

What I want to do is setup a simple websocket from my application to another website (Discord API) socket interface so I can communicate because my app and their API.

What am I doing wrong? I been trying to figure this out all day, any help is appreciated.

[Update]
I also did not find much information on any of this.

Comment: Your Visual Studio cannot find OpenSSL you need to tell it where it is. Usually in Project Properties->C++->Additional Directories

Comment: I done that. I added both the libraries and include directories.